# Pepper robot app development - Follow me as long as you see me

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I would like to make the Pepper robot follow me as long as it recognizes me until I touch the left hand.

I made the pepper recognize me with Learn face choreograph box. I also know the pepper recognize my left-hand touch using Tactile L.Hand Choregraphe box. The problem which I have is using Move Toward box. It seems that it simply report failure and stop.

I wonder anyone know how to make this app be done. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [ALTracker](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/trackers/index.html), specifically the "Move" or "Navigate" modes, that will make Pepper try to move toward it's target; in this case you should track "People" (defined by a ppid, People Perception ID).

(So if so far you're doing this in Choregraphe, you will need to define a custom box).